# erro ao conectar o mysql com o node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, node.js

estou conectar o mysql com o node mas esta dando esse erro:

> ```
> C:\E. S\dao.js:10
>   if (err) throw err
>            ^
>
> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost:806 localhost:806:3306
>     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:58:26)
>     --------------------
>     at Protocol._enqueue (C:\E. S\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
>     at Protocol.handshake (C:\E. S\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
>     at Connection.connect (C:\E. S\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:119:18)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\E. S\dao.js:9:5)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:868:12)
> ```

peguei o codigo desse site: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp

o codigo:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost:806",
  user: "root",
  password: "usbw"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Comment: Podes verificar se a porta é de fato a 806 ?

Comment: Samuel, troque a porta do host para ver se acessa: ```host: "localhost:3306",```

Comment: assim acabei de ver aqui a minha porta é 3307, obg qual quer coisa o atualizo a pergunta com os possíveis novos erros, obg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para definir a porta com a função `createConnection` você deve informar a porta dentro da propriedade `port`:

```
// ...
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 806,
  user: 'root',
  password: 'usbw',
});
// ...
```

> [**Connection options**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#connection-options)
>
> ...
>
> `port`: The port number to connect to. (Default: `3306`)
>
> ...

Em tradução livre:

> ...
>
> `port`: O número da porta a se conectar. (Padrão: `3306`)
>
> ...

Comment: nao deve ser a porta no localhost?

Comment: @SamuelSilva `localhost` é o `host`. É outra informação. A porta deve ser atribuída no atributo `port`.

Comment: assim acabei de ver aqui a minha porta é 3307, obg qual quer coisa o atualizo a pergunta com os possíveis novos erros, obg

Comment: @SamuelSilva o procedimento é você aceitar a resposta, já que ela já te atendeu e caso tenha novas dúvidas criar outra pergunta e não atualizar essa com novos erros.